# Getting images from keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, keras, title

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data_dir',
target_size = (192,192),                                                 

classes=list(classes),

batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'categorical',
subset='training')

def show_batch(image_batch,label_batch):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    for n in range(25):
        ax=plt.subplot(5,5,n+1)
        plt.imshow(image_batch[n])
        plt.title(classes[label_batch[n]==1][0].title())
        plt.axis('off')
image_batch,label_batch =next(training_set)
show_batch(image_batch,out)


Error:
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-119d7617787c> in <module>
      1 image_batch,label_batch =next(training_set)
----> 2 show_batch(image_batch,out)

<ipython-input-50-cd3820cdd66f> in show_batch(image_batch, label_batch)
      4         ax=plt.subplot(5,5,n+1)
      5         plt.imshow(image_batch[n])
----> 6         plt.title(classes[label_batch[n]==1][0].title())
      7         plt.axis('off')

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

i was trying to visualize images stored from a image data generator from keras image preprocessing module and encountered an error while ploting them